# How to create folder internal memory in Android +IOS Using titatium?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

can you please tell me how to create folder in internal memory of IOS and in android using titatinium .I want to create first folder than inside I want to create a text file in that .?

Suggest me good way to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: yes I know how to create folder in phonegap .But I don't know how to create in titanium

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read [Titanium.Filesystem module](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Filesystem) and [Titanium.Filesystem.File](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Filesystem.File)?

You can create a directory [createDirectory() method](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Filesystem.File-method-createDirectory) and create a file using the [createFile() method](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Filesystem.File-method-createFile).

Please read the documentation well and you can also refer [appcelerator titanium: Creating a new file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550971/appcelerator-titanium-creating-a-new-file).

Comment: I Thanks For help .can you please tell me where I will save this so that I will check on android simulator cocoafish-android-sdk (1).zip

Comment: I am using XP and I click get started button here I donload android SDK